# Can nuget restore be protected against name spoofing?

Tags: .net, security, nuget

Our team use internal nuget feeds. Our .net core projects then reference our internal packages using package references :

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="OurCompany.OurPackage" Version="1.01" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If my understanding is correct, a nuget restore command will try to resolve `OurCompany.OurPackage` by querying all the nuget feeds that are configured on the developer's machine. This includes our internal nuget feed, but this will also include other nuget feeds such as nuget.org (on which we depend for some external dependencies).

Does .NET/nuget offer a security mechanism that would prevent developers from accidentally downloading a malicious fake package named `OurCompany.OurPackage` from nuget.org ?

Note : a similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153475/package-dependancy-resolution-in-nuget-and-naming-conflicts) in 2014. However the accepted answer is quite old and suggests to use a third party product which acts as a proxy to nuget.org. This solution seems a little "heavyweight" for us and we would like to be sure no simpler solution exist at this time.

Comment: You can create your own `nuget.config` with internal feed for specific project/solution. You can also specify the nuget source or config file for restore command

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thank you for your answer ! If I understand correctly, I can create a `nuget.config` file inside my projects/solutions and configure this file to instruct nuget to use our internal feed. Can I however instruct nuget to only download `OurCompany.OurPackage` from our feed but allow other external dependencies to be downloaded from nuget.org ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### lock files

NuGet introduced lock files at the end of 2018 for PackageReference, and later for packages.config. There was a [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/enable-repeatable-package-restores-using-a-lock-file/) announcing the PackageReference lock file, with some information on how to use it, and there are [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#locking-dependencies) as well.

The way it protects you is that when the lock file is generated, NuGet takes a hash of the package contents and writes that to the lock file. On later restores, when the same package version is used, if the downloaded package's contents hash doesn't match, NuGet will fail the restore with an error. On build servers you should use "locked mode", which also fails restore if the restore graph is different (different versions of packages are selected).

### nuget.org prefix reservation

nuget.org supports [prefix reservation](https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/nuget-org/id-prefix-reservation). It has [some specific criteria to meet](https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/nuget-org/id-prefix-reservation#id-prefix-reservation-criteria). In the past they required at least one package to already be uploaded, I'm not sure if that's still the case. But if your company already has at least one public package on nuget.org, then you should be able reserve your company's prefix and prevent anyone else from publishing with that prefix. Note, it will not prevent people in your nuget.org organization account from accidentally publishing internal packages to nuget.org

### aggregated feed

The lock file feature above has one impactful issue. When it does detect a package with a different content hash, you're simply unable to build. NuGet doesn't try different sources trying to find a package with the expected hash. You need to clear the global packages folder on the affected machine, and while you can try again and hope that your private feed with the correct package responds faster than the other feed with the bad package, it may either be unreliable, or if the feed with the bad package is always faster, you'll be completely blocked (NuGet tries all http sources in parallel, and downloads from the fastest one).

The only current workarounds for this is to either change your package ID or version, so there's no longer a conflict with a different source, or do as the linked question/answer suggests, which is to use an aggregating source. There are [many NuGet servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview) that can do this, some are self-hosted, some are cloud hosted. If your company has an Azure DevOps account, Azure Artifacts has this functionality built-in.

By publishing your packages to your feed, you ensure that your package will always be used, and only when the package doesn't already exist in the feed, it will search the upstream sources. Just make sure that your builds are configured to use this source as your one and only source. Another advantage is that this might make NuGet restore faster, as in general the fewer sources you have, the faster restore is. As mentioned NuGet does use the fastest source when downloading, but some operations (always if you use "floating versions") require responses from all servers, so having a single source, which if you can ensure is fast, means you always have fast results in the fewest number of requests.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer ! We did consider prefix registration but nuget.org still requires that a "significant amount" of packages are already uploaded. Unfortunately we currently have no plan to upload packages to nuget.org.
Lock files look promising but (if I understand correctly) they would still offer no guarantee regarding the package origin when someone upgrades to a newer version of one of our packages.
Our own aggregated feed as the unique source of packages does seem like the most secure solution for us.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the linked question remains relevant in 2020, because filtering packages based on sources is a feature outside of NuGet's purview as a package manager. You might argue that it should be added, but considering how difficult it is to get the NuGet team to do *anything* (their GitHub repo is where feature requests go to die), I wouldn't hold out too much hope.

What you will need instead is a third-party package host (effectively your own NuGet server) that your developers will reference instead of NuGet.org. On that host you will configure the actual NuGet servers that packages can be pulled from, and the rules for resolving those packages - in your case, ensuring that package names containing a particular string or regular expression, can only be pulled from your internal NuGet sources.

You will likely also want to blacklist the nuget.org feeds on your company's firewall, except for the server that is your NuGet host.

A discussion on available NuGet hosts and their capabilities for performing the sort of filtering you require is outside the scope of this question, although [Microsoft provides a list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview). Even if you cannot find a free host that allows this functionality, it should be relatively simple to find an open-source host, and fork and modify their source code to handle your case. If you do so, please contribute those changes back to the host's project.

Comment: To be honest, we're a little bit disappointed that nuget still has no builtin feature that guarantees that a package will always be downloaded from a specific source. Thank you for the helpful information you provided ! We will investigate the solution of having our own nuget server as the only allowed source.

Comment: Believe me, you aren't the only one disappointed that NuGet has consistently failed to add useful features. I honestly don't know what they spend their time doing.